# Как сделать полностью прозрачный RichTextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, текст, richtextbox, rtf

В RichTextBox подгружаю из .rtf файла текс. Мне нужно как-то убрать белый фон за текстом. Как я могу это сделать?
Сейчас у меня есть такой код:

```
<RichTextBox x:Name="RichTextBoxForInfo" Background="Transparent" Foreground="Black">
</RichTextBox>
```

Результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Дополнение:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Содержимое .rtf документа
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вставка текста в RTB:

```
private void LoadDocx(string path)
    {
        TextRange range;
        System.IO.FileStream fStream;

        if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
        {
            range = new TextRange(RichTextBoxForInfo.Document.ContentStart, RichTextBoxForInfo.Document.ContentEnd);
            fStream = new System.IO.FileStream(path, System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
            range.Load(fStream, DataFormats.Rtf);

            fStream.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Виктор У меня почему-то нет таких свойств у RichTextBox

Comment: Я полагаю, что текст, подгруженный из файла, имеет этот фон. Сам RTB просто отображает то, что ему дали. То есть нужно либо исходный RTF чистить, либо обрабатывать документ в RTB.

Comment: @aepot Попытался раскрасить фон текста в документе, вот что получилось(прикрепил к вопросу новые скрины)

Comment: Если вам нужно форматирование текста, то мой совет, используйте современный Markdown, в интернете есть ряд решений, которые позволяют засунуть его в `RichTextBox`, даже некоторые со своими .xaml стилями, где вы можете настроить без проблем каждый .md элемент под свой вкус. А по поводу вопроса - согласен с комментарием выше, тут в самом файле скорее фон, вон даже на последнем скрине он виден, перед "Федотов" очень хороша видна некая сероватая область, которая идет под всем текстом, сплошным прямоугольником.

Comment: Как вы вставляете текст в RTB? Покажите код.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Спасибо, обращу на это внимание

Comment: @aepot Добавил код вставки текста в RTB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наткнулся на свойство Background в FlowDocument и это стало моим решением.

Код:

```
<RichTextBox x:Name="RichTextBoxForInfo" Background="Transparent">
    <FlowDocument Background="Transparent" Foreground="White"/>
</RichTextBox>
```

Результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Background="Transparent"
        WindowStyle="None"
        AllowsTransparency="True"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="400">
    <Grid Background="Transparent">
        <RichTextBox 
            Foreground="Yellow"
            FontSize="24"
            Width="320" Height="240" 
            Background="#44808F80">
        </RichTextBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]